# Use SQL Select directly in CR Function

Tags: crystal-reports

There's a working report but I wan't to change the visibility of certain rows based on a completely new DB select that should be executed when the report is created.
It would be ideal, if I could load the values of said select in an array or a list and than simply trigger certain row's visibility by comparing e.g. the Row Id with the values in the array.

Im used to solve a problem like this by creating a View that delivers all the essential information in each row and is used as the main data source but I was wondering if there's an elegant way within crystal reports to solve such a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three ways to include control data like this into the report:

1. **One row of config data:** If you can arrange it that your config data query returns one row of data, it can be just added to the data sources of the main report, without any links to tables and views already there.
2. **Config resultset for matching:** If you have to match main data results to config values row by row, e.g. by the Row Id you mentioned, add this config query to your report and link it to the main data source accordingly. (You are probably already doing this within your pre-created view on database side.)
3. **Query config by subreport:** Most flexible but also time consuming option is to add a subreport in report header, add the config data query and arrange config results into (shared) variables as needed in the subreport. Shared variable values can be used in main report then to control section visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs (User Function Libraries) listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) provides such a function.